# Nested Hide, show javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have html code like this,

```
<select id="select1">
<option value="1">..<option>
 ..
</select>

<div id="select2" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="select3" style="display:none;"></div>
```

If one option is selected, it displays corresponding div. Code I used is

```
$("#select1").change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 1) {
        $("#select2").show();
    } else {
        $("#select2").hide();
    }
    if($(this).val() == 2) {
        $("#select3").show();               
    } else {
        $("#select3").hide();
    }
    if($(this).val() == 3) {
        $("#select4").show();
    } else {                
        $("#select4").hide();
    }
});
```

If one div is displayed, I again used the same script for another select which shows/hides a textarea.

```
<div id="select2">
 <select id="select4"></select>
 <textarea id="select5" style="display:none;"></textarea>

<script>
$("#select4").change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 1) {
      $("#select5").show();
    } else {
      $("#select5").hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

But that textarea is not displaying.

Comment: `#select4` doesn't have a value so it can't see a value of `1`...

Comment: well spotted @ ?? shub ??, also you could make your code less convoluted by doing a single on change call and passing in the id or class.

Comment: use $(document).on("change", "#select4",function(){...});

Answer (score 1):

Well, the HTML you show has no option elements in the select, so the select will have no value.

If the HTML is actually different, you should edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

try this, hope it does what you are expecting :

```js
$("#select1").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    $("#select2").show();
  } else {
    $("#select2").hide();
  }
  if ($(this).val() == 2) {
    $("#select3").show();
  } else {
    $("#select3").hide();
  }

});


$("#select4").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    $("#select5").show();
  } else {
    $("#select5").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option value="1">1
  </option>
  <option value="2">2
  </option>
  <option value="3">3
  </option>

</select>


<div id="select3" style="display:none;">div2</div>


<div id="select2" style="display:none;">
  <select id="select4">
    <option value="1">1
    </option>
    <option value="2">2
    </option>
  </select>
  <textarea id="select5" style="display:none;"></textarea>
</div>
```